# Records all delete when I restart `amber watch`

Tags: crystal-lang, amber-framework

This is really strange and I've never encountered a bug like this.

I run `amber db seed` and my records are created, I can see my records in the UI, a simple `index` scaffold.

[image]

Then ctrl+c the `amber watch`, run `amber watch` again and refresh refresh refresh and suddenly they all vanish!

[image]

Why would restarting `amber watch` cause all my records to disappear?

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that earlier versions of Amber used to run the tests without the `AMBER_ENV=test` environment variable so tests & development shared the same database.

The watch command does run the specs in the same time where by default you have a command like `Platform.clear` generated in it, thus clearing your database every time it's executed.

In order to fix this, modify your `.amber.yml` file to specify that you run specs with the test database:

```
  spec:
    run_commands:
      - AMBER_ENV=test crystal spec
```

Comment: This doesn't do the trick for me now. Any other suggestions?